# SQL update row with info from another row (rookie)

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL so be gentle! I'm working for a charity in London so I'm having a stab at SQL and I've gotten stuck with something you can probably all do with your eyes shut.

I've got a table with rows that I want to update:

[image: The table]

It's a table showing up potential duplicate records in our database. There's a stored procedure that creates a criterion field from data on a customer account and if criterion fields from 2 records match, they are flagged as potential duplicates.

We have some known duplicates that we had to create a while ago that have `Placeholder` as the last name.

The criterion field matches other 'real' records with real last names that we want to keep.

What I want to do is:

1. update the status of the `Placeholder` ones to `Delete`; and the 'real' ones to `Keep` (even I can totally blitz that!)
2. update the keep ID field of the `Placeholder` ones so it's the customer_no field of the row with the matching criterion field

Once that's done, another stored procedure will take it from there.

Help!

Comment: Howdy... Couple of things, can you tag your dbms (sql server, oracle, mysql, etc)? Also, can you post what you've tried so far? Finally, that data would be easier for us to handle if you post it in your Q as a table instead of an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow.

If I have understood you correctly you need something like this:

```
declare @customers table(
    customer_no int NOT NULL, 
    matching_criteria varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    lname varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    keepID int NULL,
    [status] varchar(50) NULL);

INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(1, 'a', 'Smith', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(2, 'a', 'Placeholder', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(3, 'b', 'Jones', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(4, 'b', 'Placeholder', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(5, 'c', 'Brown', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(6, 'c', 'Placeholder', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(7, 'd', 'Williams', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(8, 'd', 'Placeholder', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(9, 'e', 'Taylor', null, null);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES(10, 'e', 'Placeholder', null, null);

SELECT * FROM @customers;

UPDATE @customers set [status] = case lname WHEN 'Placeholder' THEN 'DELETE' ELSE 'Keep' END;

SELECT * FROM @customers;

UPDATE k 
SET keepID = d.customer_no
FROM 
@customers k
INNER JOIN @customers d
on k.matching_criteria = d.matching_criteria
WHERE d.[status] = 'Delete' AND k.[status] = 'Keep';

SELECT * FROM @customers;
```

If you are using SQL Server you can paste this in a Query window and observe the results.

Please for future reference tell us which DB you are using, as the answers do vary from db to db.  The above is specifically SQL Server.  Whilst most dbs will behave similarly, some do not.  The above updates on a join.  Oracle, for example, does not allow this, so the syntax when using Oracle is different - Oracle can of course achieve the same thing, it just uses different SQL to do so.